# How to count all elements with 1 condition

Tags: php, function, count

I am using this PHP function `$price = count(SellerProductId);`

to count all the `SellerProductId` from an output But I would like to ignore this one `[SellerProductId] => Array`

For example in this output the desired result would be 1
instead of 2:

```
[RowId] => 0
[SellerProductId] => 1_SONJA-450445-40
[ShippingDateMax] => 2021-02-16T13:19:25.333
[ShippingDateMin] => 2021-02-16T13:19:25.333
[Sku] => MP18343394-0006

[RowId] => 1
[SellerProductId] => Array
    (
    )
[ShippingDateMax] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
[ShippingDateMin] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
[Sku] => INTERETBCA
```

How should I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Just check to see if `SellerProductId` is an empty array. If so, skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the `id` [columns](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) into an array, then pass it through [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php) to remove every entry which is [falsy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to stip the empty arrays.

```
$a = [
    ['id' => '1'],
    ['id' => []],
];

var_dump(count($a)); // 2
var_dump(count(array_filter(array_column($a, 'id')))); // 1
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/sZD0V).

### Updated answer

To find all occurences of `"[SellerProductId] => Array"` you can use [substr_count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count).

Workind [example](https://3v4l.org/sGlKa).

In case the file is event too lage to read in PHP at once you will have to go through it by chunks (read line by line for example -> fopen + fgets).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is that there are too many arrays in the output file and I can't find the accurate variable this is why I just wanted to look for a string named "[SellerProductId] => Array"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)) In your example it works but not in the website,  maybe it is because the code is serialized in my case.I have tried to reproduce the code here maybe it would be more helpful  https://3v4l.org/MZH3C

Comment: @Cyril-260 Check [this](https://3v4l.org/ElcdB). I highly suggest you to get the basics before you try anything like this. Your string wasnt even encapsulated right. Furthermore you are looking for a string which is generated by `print_r`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your answers it helps me to understand better the problem and get more familiar with it. Your code works fine but unfortunately it doesn't work on the website I get the result 3.53 instead of 2, it seems it adds the 1.53 fees which are in the output file to the result (2 + 1.53). I have actually 2 distinct files 1 with the PHP code and 1 output file which contains the serialized code and this is why I don't know how to put them both in here :(